# How to re-use collapse method with ElementRef (collected with @ViewChild)

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on a personal project, which needs to display multiple sections of text. To minimize the space of the sections, i've wrote a collapse method to collapse those sections onClick.

The main question is that i can't figure out how to re-use that method for all the sections on the webpage, since i'm collecting the div element with @ViewChild - ElementRef. At the moment there is only one solution i can come up with, and that is to copy this method for all the sections in want to collapse. Although, i'm pretty sure there is a much cleaner way.

Here is what the my .ts file from my main.component looks like at the moment:

```
@ViewChild('contentLorem')
   contentLorem: ElementRef;

   collapsed: boolean = false;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  collapse(){

      if (this.contentLorem.nativeElement.style.maxHeight){
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.contentLorem.nativeElement, 'maxHeight', 'null');
      } else {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.contentLorem.nativeElement, 'maxHeight', `${this.contentLorem.nativeElement.scrollHeight + "px"}`);
        this.collapsed = true;
      } 

  }

  destroy(){
    this.contentLorem.nativeElement.style.maxHeight = null;
    this.collapsed = false;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="section-block">
      <h5 class="section-header">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
      <p class="section-par">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit laborum illo saepe, eveniet
        et quisquam quaerat
        vel. Similique dolores, molestiae eos est maxime earum deserunt!</p>
        <div #contentLorem class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <button *ngIf="collapsed == false" (click)="collapse()" class="btn btn-primary">Lees meer</button>
        <button *ngIf="collapsed == true" (click)="destroy()" class="btn btn-primary">Minder</button>
    </div>
```

I hope someone is able to provide a cleaner solution for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'fix' your issue is by using `@ViewChildren` and some array which tracks whether or not this item is collapsed.

I put the 'fix' in quotes, because this feels like something that needs to be done in a separate component, if you want to add the button, or a directive if you just want the logic. I'll show you a component implementation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'collapse-content',
  template: `
    <div class="content" 
      [style.maxHeight.px]="collapsed ? content?.scrollHeight : null"
      #content
    >
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>

    <button (click)="collapsed = !collapsed">
      {{ collapsed ? 'Minder' : 'Lees meer' }}
    </button>
  `,
  styles: [
    '.content { max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden }'
  ]
})
export class CollapseContentComponent  {
  collapsed = false;
}
```

And you can change all your content inside your parent template to something like this:

```
<div class="section-block">
  <h5 class="section-header"> <!-- --> </h5>

  <p class="section-par"> <!-- --> </p>

  <collapse-content>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
    </p>
  </collapse-content>
</div>
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zaj1ir

Comment: That doens't seem to be it after all... sorry. I'm getting the error ' Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined' in the Collapse-component. I've implemented the component exactly how you showed.

Comment: @R-deBruijn can you try again, I've removed the 'nativeElement'. It's untested code, so it's bound to have some errors :)

Comment: @R-deBruijn I've also added a working stackblitz example

Comment: that did'nt do it either, the content is displayed by default. Clicking the button will result in changing the buttons value, nothing else. Console i clean now though.

Comment: Now it's working, since the style was added. Not sure why that was the problem, since i added no style myself in the collapse-component. Great fix though, many thanks to you @PierreDuc !

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the reference variable `#contentLorem` to the `collapse()`.